# word for making money from a situation

Tags: word-request

Some people try making money, or even credit (as in respect, poor word maybe), upon often a bad situation (natural disasters come to mind), I feel there is a word for it, for them to _ on the situation.

Edit, I think the word I'm looking for is related to the word *capitalism*

Comment: to **cash in** on the situation

Comment: *exploit* a situation.

Comment: **Capitalize** on the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to **cash in** on the situation

Or, if you need a word related to *capitalism*,

> to **capitalize** on the situation

Answer (score 1):

The word is *cash in on* (it's an inseparable phrasal verb, the object must come at the end) as pointed out. It's used when you want to  benefit yourself or make money on something and it doesn't matter how you do so, even if it's unfairly done.